# What is the difference between ThreadPool and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

i want to know what is the difference when i use this code in python

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

and when i use the normal **python threading with queues** like this

```
import threading
import queue
```

> both are using **multi threading** not **multi processing**

i just wanted to know if there is any difference between them not in only syntax but in the code process

Comment: With a pool you have to write less code on your own if you have a lot of jobs which should be distributed among a few threads. Mainly that's it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i dont understand, my question is if i have list of urls for example and i want to make request on them with requests module, what is the difference if i used ThreadPool.map and put the urls list and the function and when i put the urls in queue and use python threading module

Comment: Not much. The ThreadPool will just care about some things automatically, like the number of threads and that each thread has something to do. With a queue you have to do that yourself (although it shouldn't be much work here).

Comment: Threads are expensive to create and take resources to exist. The thread pool allows you to create and reuse a limited amount of threads, instead of creating / destroying new ones.